# DriveInfo in VB not working on some computers

Tags: vb.net

I created a program that checks the C drive space utilization of a Windows Server using the code below (I found this method on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.availablefreespace(v=vs.110).aspx)

It is working just fine in some Windows server but on others it won't work. I did not encounter any exception error, the exe just closes out. Tried running as Admin as well. Can you help if there are other ways to do this? or a Windows configuration that I need to modify?

Here's the snippet for visibility

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim allDrives() As DriveInfo = DriveInfo.GetDrives()

        Dim d As DriveInfo
        For Each d In allDrives
            Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name)
            Console.WriteLine("  Drive type: {0}", d.DriveType)
            If d.IsReady = True Then
                Console.WriteLine("  Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel)
                Console.WriteLine("  File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat)
                Console.WriteLine( _
                    "  Available space to current user:{0, 15} bytes", _
                    d.AvailableFreeSpace)

                Console.WriteLine( _
                    "  Total available space:          {0, 15} bytes", _
                    d.TotalFreeSpace)

                Console.WriteLine( _
                    "  Total size of drive:            {0, 15} bytes ", _
                    d.TotalSize)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you check the event-log on the server after the exe has closed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Enterprise environment with a group policy enforced with no installation occurring I have encountered this exact behavior. Your being blocked on the computer that stops specific operation types (some exe, some msi etc).

The solution I remember was you can't have the exe started from that computer, it has to be ran from an external source. i.e. keep the .exe on the server but have it check the local and have any local resource needs be in a temp location.

Sorry I don't have more details but it has been 6 years since I worked on that application.

Hope that helps.